# Is there a recommended way of selling a 3-pack of a product for a discounted rate?

Tags: shopify

I have a product on a Shopify website that is normally $20 but when buying a pack of three it becomes $45 total (ie: $15 each). The three pack has a separate SKU, but I would love it if my customers could simply have buttons on the product page to switch between the variations. The pack of three should have color selection options, but it should be clear to the user that all the products in the pack will be the same color. If you have any advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches, but since you haven't provided a code example of what have you tried I will only list them.

#### App

You can use a discount APP

#### Different product

You can use a different product that will handle the bundle price

#### Shopify Scripts

If you are on a Shopify Plus store you have the option of writing custom Ruby scripts that can modify the cart items and their price. You can write a script that will modify the item price based on properties that are tied to the bundle product.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to add another variant option. Just call it as `Pack of 3` and set to this variant a different SKU and a price of $45. Based on your question description this will totally suit your case.